# Converting JSON string to NSDictionary in DetailViewController

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, nsdictionary, nsdata

Trying to figure out why the json segue from tableviewcontroller to detailviewcontroller isn't working. Did an NSLog to see if data was pass, this is what showed up in dvc.

```
"data.detail" NSLog:

(
        {
        emails =         {
            10 = j;
            11 = k;
            12 = l;
            9 = i;
        };
        links =         {
            1 = a;
            2 = b;
            3 = c;
            4 = d;
        };
        location =         {
            13 = m;
            14 = n;
            15 = o;
            16 = p;
        };
        numbers =         {
            5 = e;
            6 = f;
            7 = g;
            8 = h;
        };
    }
)
```

Then I...

Tried to convert the json data into a tableview in the detailviewcontroller.

```
NSString *rawString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data.detail];
NSString *jsonString = rawString;
NSData *JSONdata = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *jsonError = nil;
```

But converting JSON to NSData then NSDictionary only output "null" in NSLog.

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONdata options:0 error:&jsonError];
NSArray *items = [dic valueForKeyPath:@"email"];
NSLog(@"dic %@", dic);
NSLog(@"items %@", items);
```

Help! Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you sure the json syntax is ok? It starts with "(" and ends with ")", are them right?

Comment: I also change the json and added "[" and "]" to see if would work but still null.

Comment: data.detail is not valid JSON. And don't use valueForKeyPath but objectForKey, which is ten times faster and unlike valueForKeyPath will always work.

Comment: The way you create rawString is rather stupid. Why don't you just use data.detail?

Comment: Your best friend is here :  http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below line of code from

```
NSArray *items = [dic valueForKeyPath:@"email"];
```

to

```
NSArray *items = [dic valueForKeyPath:@"emails"];
```

if still you got nslog nil than change

```
NSString *rawString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data.detail];
```

to like this

```
NSString *rawString = @"{\"emails\" :{\"10\" : \"j\",\"11\" : \"k\",\"12\" : \"l\",\"9\" : \"i\"},\"links\" :{\"1\" : \"a\",\"2\" : \"b\",\"3\" : \"c\",\"4\" : \"d\"}}";
```

Comment: Thank you, the rawsting format that you posted help a lot and this is my fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there your `JSON` isn't valid so it won't work ...

so first of all look at an example of a `JSON` : http://json.org/example

Then you can try your `JSON` here : jsonlint.com

Here is the beginning of your `JSON` with a good format :

```
{
"emails": {
    "9": "i",
    "10": "j",
    "11": "k",
    "12": "l"
},
"links": {
    "1": "a",
    "2": "b",
    "3": "c",
    "4": "d"
}
}
```

Mainly changed the `=` to `:` and `;` to `,` and added some `"`

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *rawString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data.detail];
```

There are two possibilities, and you are not showing enough information:

Either data.detail is an NSString. In that case this line of code is utterly useless, because it is just an expensive way of making a copy of the string, which doesn't contain any JSON at all.

Or data.detail is an NSDictionary. In which case your whole code is absolutely misguided nonsense, because in that case you have an NSDictionary, try to convert it to a JSON string with code that doesn't work, convert that string to NSData, and convert the NSData back to a dictionary, which is where you started!

Out of sheer morbid curiosity, which one is it?